# How to get the Published or Archived revision of a node

Tags: 8, nodes

I'm trying to compare some field values from the edit form of a node to the published/archived field values. However I'm running to an issue where when im trying to load the Node object using
`Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid)`
It's returning the last saved draft revision. How do i get the Node object of the published/archived revision?

P.S. Content Moderation is turned on, and content type is assigned to a workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a direct database query in your function, then load the specific revision.

```
$connection = \Drupal::database();
$query = $connection->query("SELECT vid FROM {node_field_data} WHERE nid = :nid",
    [':nid' => $node_nid,]);
$node_revision_id = $query->fetchField();

$node_revision = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->loadRevision($node_revision_id);
```

Untested code, but this should put you on the right track.  Might also be worth confirming in your SQL query that "WHERE status = 1" to confirm that the node is still published.

Comment: Thanks. But this didn't work. It gave me the same node as ```Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid)``` which is the draft revision and not the currently published revision.

Comment: Actually disregard my comment above this works. However, the condition to check status/moderation state is important because, a node might not have a published/archived version yet.